# how to manipulate colors to quickly update many dots on html canvas

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas

I wrote a simulation. There's an animation component.

There are approximately 4 million coordinates.

Every coordinate is reported in a text file, text1.txt.

Every coordinate either changes or is deleted within 10000 frames.

Every coordinate change or addition or deletion is reported in another text file, text2.txt. On average, text2.txt contains under 1000 changes.

I want to draw every point reported in text1.txt.

**My main idea**

If I could work solely off text2.txt, I would need my animation to 'warm up' for a while before it would be up to date. At 30fps, it would be about 6 minutes. But then it would be consistently up to date.

For the time being, my animation is always a little delayed. I have 2 canvases : canvas1 is visible and shows the last animation to be completed, while canvas2 is not visible. I break up reading text1.txt into pieces, mapping it onto canvas2 behind the scenes. Then when canvas2 is done, I copy canvas2 to canvas1, and reset canvas2.

It would be interesting to me to use text2.txt instead. Is there some way for me to remove a given circle by drawing a new circle over top of it ? Imagine a given pixel has the original color c0. And because of the circle I drew, it got hit with color c1. So now the pixel has the new color c2=f(c0,c1). I'm trying to get a color c3, such that when I layer c3 onto c2, I get c0, like c0=g(c3,c2).

The point is to save time by avoiding a redrawing of every point.

Anyhow, is this approach, or something similar, possible ?

Comment: While the approach is _possible_, it's not generally how things are done. Almost always, you want to wipe the whole canvas and redraw everything per frame. If you have a performance problem, there may be a better way to solve it than this. It's best to provide full context, preferably a [mcve], and describe the original performance problem X, rather than only asking about your proposed solution Y [absent any context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: With 4 million records, you'd need at least as much pixels to not have two records overlap on the same pixel coordinate, this means you need at least a 2000x2000px canvas, **and** that every records is only 1px wide, **and** that every new record is ever only added on an empty coordinate. Are all these constraints ensured? If not, you can't clear the pixels where a previous record was drawn, because it would also affect any other records that lie on the same pixels. Just clear all and redraw all. And show us your actual slow code so that we can help improve its perfs.

Comment: One common mistake is to draw each entity individually. If many share the same color, then it's better to group them by color and draw one big path made of all the similar entities, so that you have the less possible calls to `stroke()` or `fill()`. If it's still not enough, then you could split the rendering across a few  layers, hoping that only a few of these layers will need an update every frame. You'd have to test how many is a good balance between perfs and memory usage.`

Comment: @Kaiido Let's say for simplicity that each circle is limited to 1x1 pixel. For a given pixel of the canvas, I expect many circles to contribute to the final pixel value. In fact, the effect depends on it (more opaque regions are higher density). Sorting could be possible, but each object's color is itself a function of the evolution of other variables in the simulation. I'm trying to avoid looping over all the data per frame (I don't even know if I could without my pc fans expressing disapproval). The way I am doing it now, it's sort of in layers.

Comment: @Kaiido But I have another idea. If given an existing drawing, I know I need to delete an element, which is drawn at pixel p0, I can get the current color of pixel p0, say it is c0. If I know that the element I want to remove has color c1, I know it is contributing to c0 already. I could calculate the color c2, to which when c1 is added, produces c0. Then I can just remove all color from pixel p0. And I could then assign it color c2. Maybe I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the bit about mixing colours means, but yes you can just draw over other colours.

However, drawing circles is not always precise, you can get some leftover colour around the edges.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
const colourInput = document.getElementById('colour-input');
const drawButton = document.getElementById('draw-button');
const form = document.getElementById('my-form');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw(colour) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = colour;
  ctx.fill();
}

function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  draw(colourInput.value);
  colourInput.value = '';
}

form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
draw('red');
```

```html
<p>Type a colour and press enter</p>
<canvas
  id="my-canvas"
  width="200"
  height="150"
  style="border: 1px solid grey"
></canvas>
<br />
<form id="my-form">
<label>Colour:</label>
<input id="colour-input"/>
</form>
```